# UIBezierPath - byRoundingCorners - Rect

Tags: ios, swift

I have a very easy view controller..

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let f = TstKocka(frame: CGRectMake(100,100, 150, 150))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(f)

    }

}
```

And I have a UIView class:

```
class TstKocka: UIView {


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        var path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.AllCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0))

        path.lineWidth = 1.0
       path.stroke()

    }

}
```

And I'm trying to create a rounded rect but I don't know how to do. I've read lot of tutorials but none of them worked for me.Please help me.

Comment: Try to provide an example of how you were attempting to create a rounded rect. Also provide any errors or other side effects you were noticing. These simple steps would improve the question by a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are not providing a fill color i guess your rect shall have a clear color. to make that work change your initwithframe to the following:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    opaque = false
}
```

then increase cornerradii value (to 20.0, 20.0 for example) to see that it works! :)

**EDIT**

filling is actually as simple as stroking:

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.AllCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20.0, height: 20.0))
path.lineWidth = 1.0

UIColor.blueColor().setFill() // or whatever fill color you like
path.fill()

UIColor.redColor().setStroke()
path.stroke()
```

Comment: without this line: opaque = false my rect was full black and i couldn't see any rounding at the corners. now i added this line as you wrote and it is working and i can see rounding corners! thank you. But, how can i do to fill my rect with any color and then rounding the corners?  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a rounded rect view that clips the content, you should use layer masks or the simple `-cornerRadius` property on the views layer, setting also the `-borderWidth`.
 
If you just want a view background rounded rect, before stroking you should set the stroke color.
I don't know swift but in objC could be something like this

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect) rect {
 UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:5.0];
 [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
 [bezierPath stroke];
}
```

In Swift probably:

```
  override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.AllCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0))
    UIColor.redColor().setStroke() 
        path.lineWidth = 1.0
       path.stroke()

    }
```